# How to check android app, intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am copy some images from internet and create a game, after submitting it google play store it was removed by google and I got a warning letter. "**REASON FOR SUSPENSION**: Your app is in violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy."

I don't know the copied image/code is protected by any authority. How can I find? Is any website to find it before submitting it google play store.